# How to nest Context and MUI's theme provider?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, themes, darkmode

So I currently have a state to toggle dark / light mode on a website with lots of nested components.  I have a root App.js:

```
function App() {
    return (
        <DarkModeProvider>
            <div className="App">
                <HomePage />
            </div>
        </DarkModeProvider>
    );
}
```

The DarkModeProvider is my react context, and in the next component I have a layout where I have my navigation and routing, that is wrapped in the ThemeProvider:

```
const HomePage = () => {
const { isDarkTheme } = useContext(DarkModeContext);

return (
    <ThemeProvider theme={isDarkTheme ? createTheme(darkTheme) : 

createTheme(lightTheme)}>
            <DrawerProvider>
                <Router>
                    <Box sx={{ display: "flex" }}>
                        <Box>
                            <HomePageInner />
                        </Box>

                        <Routes>
                            <Route path="/inventory" element={<Inventory />} />
                            <Route path="/orders" element={<Orders />} />
                            <Route path="/vendors" element={<Vendors />} />
                        </Routes>
                    </Box>
                </Router>
            </DrawerProvider>
        </ThemeProvider>
    );
};
```

It works fine, however, I'd like to access the theme context in my "app" class that's in the root App component.  If I wrap the DarkModeProvider with the ThemeProvider, I don't have access to the state of the dark / light mode, if I wrap the ThemeProvider with the DarkModeProvider, I lose access to the isDarkTheme state from my context.

Is there a better practice to format this?  What I really want is to have a css / style sheet in the source folder as the same level as the app component.  I'm unsure how to access my theme provider when it's not in my app component.  OR how to have my dark mode state accessible while wrapped inside of the theme provider (or vice versa).

For example my App.CSS:

```
body {
    background-color: theme.primary.palette.main; 
    /* I would like the body to follow my MUI theme. */
}

a {
    color: inherit;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

Dark Mode Provider:

```
import { createContext, useState } from "react";

const DarkModeContext = createContext();

export const DarkModeProvider = ({ children }) => {
    const [isDarkTheme, setIsDarkTheme] = useState(false);

    const changeTheme = () => {
        setIsDarkTheme(!isDarkTheme);
    };

    return (
        <DarkModeContext.Provider
            value={{
                isDarkTheme,
                changeTheme,
            }}
        >
            {children}
        </DarkModeContext.Provider>
    );
};

export default DarkModeContext;
```

Comment: Where exactly in App component do you want to access the theme context?

Comment: Really the main thing I'd like to access is the 'app' class from app.css.  Primarily for the background color and font color, which I'd also like to change for night mode.

Comment: Can you write the code for it for better understanding?

Comment: Sure I edited the original post to include the app.css.  Both App.js and the App.css are in the same folder, while the HomePage component is a child of the App.js

Comment: Have you tried moving the `ThemeProvider` component inside App.js file nested inside the `DarkModeProvider`? I don't see any reason to include `ThemeProvider` inside HomePage instead of App.js. You can create a state inside App.js for isDarkTheme so it's accessible inside App.js for ThemeProvider

Comment: Also why do you need DarkModeProvider? If you pass down dark or light theme inside ThemeProvider, I think you can access the active theme value from MUI

Comment: I use the DarkModeProvider context to toggle the state  of light / dark mode without prop drilling, If I set my state in the app.js I could prop drill the state and toggle function,  is that what you mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can move the `ThemeProvider` component inside App.js file and have a state there for `isDarkTheme` which you can then use both for `DarkModeProvider` and `ThemeProvider`

```
function App() {
  const [isDarkTheme, setIsDarkTheme] = useState(false);

  const changeTheme = () => {
    setIsDarkTheme(!isDarkTheme);
  };
  
  return (
      <DarkModeProvider value={{ isDarkTheme, changeTheme }}>
        <ThemeProvider theme={isDarkTheme ? createTheme(darkTheme) : createTheme(lightTheme)}>
          <div className="App">
            <HomePage />
          </div>
        </ThemeProvider> 
      </DarkModeProvider>
  );
}
```

Dark Mode Provider:

```
import { createContext } from "react";

const DarkModeContext = createContext();

export const DarkModeProvider = ({ children, value }) => {
    return (
        <DarkModeContext.Provider value={value}>
          {children}
        </DarkModeContext.Provider>
    );
};

export default DarkModeContext;
```

Comment: Apologies, comments are certainly not the best place to place code.  With this my state no longer changes with the nested navbar that has an onClick to toggle the isDarkTheme state.

Comment: Please update the code in the question

Comment: Please check the updated answer. You need to have everything related to state inside App.js and just pass down the `value` to the provider

Comment: Thank you so much for your help!!! I didn't think to pass props into the Provider and use it that way (I'm very new to useContext).

Comment: You are welcome, I'm glad I could help